# Reading through each character after using fgets in C

Tags: c

After I use fgets in order to read a file line by line, I want to make sure that each character satisfies a certain criteria.  After I read each line and store it in the variable "line", I tried to look at what the characters are by saying line[0] but that gave me a seg fault.  Any clue why?

```
char line[MAXSIZE];
if ( mapfile == NULL ) {
    printf("%s is a mapfile that doesn't exist.  Please try again", argv[i+1]);
    exit(0);
} else {
    while( fgets(line,sizeof(line),mapfile)!=NULL ){
        printf("%s",line[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value at line[MAXSIZE-1] ? How many characters you can fill in line at max so that printf goes fine ? Is line initialized?

Comment: If you want an array of all of the lines, then `line` should be `char *line[MAXSIZE]`  Then you have an array of lines of lenght MAXSIZE...

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the address of the initial character of the line to `printf`, not the character itself:

```
while( fgets(line,sizeof(line),mapfile)!=NULL ){
    printf("%s", &line[0]);
}
```

or

```
while( fgets(line,sizeof(line),mapfile)!=NULL ){
    printf("%s", line);
}
```

> to clarify my question, if the first line in my file is `"abcds"`, how do I get just `"a"` or `"b"`

Use `line[0]` or `line[1]` with `%c` format specifier after making sure that the line is not empty:

```
if (strlen(line) != 0) {
    printf("%c", line[0]);
}
```

**Note:** Since the `if` branch exits, you can move the loop to top level to reduce the level of nesting:

```
char line[MAXSIZE];
if ( mapfile == NULL ) {
    printf("%s is a mapfile that doesn't exist.  Please try again", argv[i+1]);
    exit(0);
}
while( fgets(line,sizeof(line),mapfile)!=NULL ){
    printf("%s", line);
}
```

Comment: to clarify my question, if the first line in my file is "abcds", how do I get just "a" or "b"

Answer (score 2):

You get [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you tell `printf` to print a *string* but your argument is a single character.

If you want to print the string in `line`, then give the string (the array) as argument, if you want to print a single character use the `"%c"` format code.

Comment: @OJyoplait It sure should have worked, it should have printed the first character in the string. Maybe you're confused since you din't print a newline after the character, so you didn't see it in front of the command terminal prompt or something?

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple printf needs the char * pointer, and instead you're sending it the value of of the first character.

Instead the code should be

```
char line[MAXSIZE];
if ( mapfile == NULL ) {
    printf("%s is a mapfile that doesn't exist.  Please try again", argv[i+1]);
    exit(0);
} else {
    while( fgets(line,sizeof(line),mapfile)!=NULL ){
        printf("%s",line);
    }
}
```